# How do I pass only some values into args object?

Tags: typescript, object, arguments, intellisense, args

Is there a way to only pass in one argument into args and let other values be default in TypeScript? I dont want "args = {}" and declaring defaults within the function due to intellisense.

```
function generateBrickPattern (
    wallWidth: number,
    wallHeight: number,
    args = {
  maxBrickWidth: 100,
  maxBrickHeight: 50,
  minBrickWidth:  50,
  minBrickHeight: 25
}) {}

generateBrickPattern(500,500,{maxBrickWidth: 75}) //Prefered

generateBrickPattern(500,500,{maxBrickWidth: 75, 
                              maxBrickHeight: 50,  
                              minBrickWidth:  50,
                              minBrickHeight: 25}) //Not wanted
```

The prefered syntax gives the following error.

> Argument of type '{ maxBrickWidth: number; }' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '{ maxBrickWidth: number; maxBrickHeight: number;
>   minBrickWidth: number; minBrickHeight: number; }...'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by destructuring `args` with default values:

```
function generateBrickPattern (
    wallWidth: number,
    wallHeight: number,
    {
        maxBrickWidth: maxBrickWidth = 100,
        maxBrickHeight: maxBrickHeight = 50,
        minBrickWidth: minBrickWidth = 50,
        minBrickHeight: minBrickHeight = 25
    } = {}
) {
    console.log(maxBrickWidth);
}
```

If you don't want to destructure you could merge the provided `args` with the defaults like this:

```
interface BrickPatternOptions {
    maxBrickWidth: number;
    maxBrickHeight: number;
    minBrickWidth: number;
    minBrickHeight: number;
}

function generateBrickPattern (
    wallWidth: number,
    wallHeight: number,
    args: Partial<BrickPatternOptions> = {}
) {
    const options: BrickPatternOptions = {
        maxBrickWidth: 100,
        maxBrickHeight: 50,
        minBrickWidth: 50,
        minBrickHeight: 25,
        ...args
    };

    console.log(options.maxBrickWidth);
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion seems really close to what I want.

2 minor things that would improve that solution for me.

Can I get the function call "generateBrickPattern(1000, 1000, {})" to work without the empty object? That is:  generateBrickPattern(1000, 1000)

Is there a way to have the optional args bundled into an object like "args.maxBrickWidth" as in the original question? (Might be unuseful)

Comment: You can default the argument to empty object to make it optional. I updated the code to show it. Unfortunately i don't know of a way to get the arguments bundled as an object directly. If you really need them bundled you could use the second code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to actually define the type for the last argument, and not let TypeScript infer it.

Try this:

```
interface BrickPatternOptions {
    maxBrickWidth?: number;
    maxBrickHeight?: number;
    minBrickWidth?: number;
    minBrickHeight?: number;
}

function generateBrickPattern (
    wallWidth: number,
    wallHeight: number,
    args: BrickPatternOptions = {
  maxBrickWidth: 100,
  maxBrickHeight: 50,
  minBrickWidth:  50,
  minBrickHeight: 25
}) {}
```

Alternatively, you could also inline it if you wanted to:

```
function generateBrickPattern (
    wallWidth: number,
    wallHeight: number,
    args: {
      maxBrickWidth?: number,
      maxBrickHeight?: number,
      minBrickWidth?: number,
      minBrickHeight?: number
    } = {
      maxBrickWidth: 100,
      maxBrickHeight: 50,
      minBrickWidth:  50,
     minBrickHeight: 25
    }) {}
```

Comment: I don't belive this solve the problem in the question. The question was hot to get TS to merge the default values for the properties of the parameter with the values for the properties passed in

Comment: `generateBrickPattern(500,500,{maxBrickWidth: 75})`  the expected value for `args` would be `{
      maxBrickWidth: 75,
      maxBrickHeight: 50,
      minBrickWidth:  50,
     minBrickHeight: 25
    }` Your solution does not fo that

Comment: Oh, I see. If that's the case then I'm not aware of a solution that does not include merging with defaults in the function's body :(